# Zhegalkin polynomial Boolean algebra

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

I have to find the Zhegalkin polynomial of $ (x\rightarrow y)\rightarrow z  $. Please tell me if this is right: my polynomial is of this kind $ a_{0} + a_{1}x + a_{2}y + a_{3}z + a_{4}xy + a_{5}yz + a_{6}xz + a_{7}xyz $ , I then make a truth table and from the values of that truth table i find the coefficients $a_{0},a_{1}...$ I also want to ask if I have something more complex as a statement is it useful to use equivalence transitions and can I get the Zhegalkin polynomial using only equivalence transitions ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to get the Zhegalkin polynomial for your expression:

The Zhegalkin polynomial for $a\rightarrow b$ is $1+a+ab$ (all addition is done mod 2).

So the polynomial for $(x\rightarrow y) \rightarrow z$ is $$1+(1+x+xy)+(1+x+xy)z=x+xy+z+xz+xyz$$